# How to code a for or while loop which prints list's values from a initial index value to an end one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to print a specific range of a list's number using for or while loop.

For example:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,]
```

from li.index[3] to li.index[7]

```
Output: 3,4,5,6,7
```

I've tried things like:

```
for i in listName in range(listName.index(3), listName.index(7),1):
```

Comment: `for item in li[2:8]: print(item)`. Remember that indexing starts at zero and the last item 8 (the 9th item) is excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use range

```
for num in range(2,7):
    print(li[num])
```

or just array slicing

```
for num in li[2:7]:
    print(num)
```